# Windows Phone io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've specified the path to video file like this:

```
VideoPath = string.Format("/Content/Videos/{0}", VideoFileName)
```

But when I try to invoke it in MediaPlayerLauncher I get FileNotFoundException

```
  MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
  mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri(VideoPath , UriKind.Relative);
  mediaPlayerLauncher.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.All;
```

Any solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your video file exists there? Do you play videos from isolated storage or embedded with you application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394004%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) try that:

```
mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Data; // If you open media from isolated storage    
// or     
mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Install; // If you open media from application project


mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri(videoPath , UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: Maybe something with MediaPlayerLauncher?

Comment: Thanks! Worked with `mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Install;` and full path to file